# How to reverse the bend in a 2 DOF arm using inverse kinematics

Tags: inverse, kinematics

I have the inverse kinematics working, but the arm bends the wrong way. I'm really new to this type of math, so please have patience. Here's the equations:

[math equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeoQG.png)

[image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oerJ4.png)

l1 and l2 are the lengths of each segment(2 segments) and the thetas are the angles that they are at. There should be two different positions that will reach the same point, and I want to be able to pick which one I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put $\pm$ sign in
$$
\theta_2=\pm \arctan(\ldots,\ldots)
$$
to get two solutions.